# QtWidget displaying QComboBox comes up empty

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm writing a QtWidget that displays a QComboBox (drop down menu) using PyQt5. However, it's coming up empty. Does anyone know why?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, formname = "Test"):
        super().__init__()
        self.formname = formname
        self.impute_methods = ["Method 1", "Method 2"]

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(self.formname)
        Form.resize(1154, 902)
        self._create_buttons(Form)
        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def _create_buttons(self, Form):
        self.test_box = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.test_box.addItems(self.impute_methods)
        self.test_box.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 190, 150, 27))
        self.test_box.setObjectName("test_box")

    def selectionchange(self, i):
        print(i)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate(self.formname, "Test"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    tester = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Test()
    ui.setupUi(tester)
    tester.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is a screenshot of what I see:

[image]

Comment: Because you didn't use a layout.

Comment: Could you expand on that a bit, perhaps in the comments? Thanks.

Comment: `layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self); layout.addWidget(self.test_box)`. [Layout Management](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/layout.html).

Answer (score 0):

set parent for comboBox to place it on `Test()`:

```
def _create_buttons(self, Form):
    self.test_box = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
    ...
```

and for ui to place it on the dialog:

```
...
ui = Test()
ui.setParent(tester)
...
```